# Disable WooCommerce New order email notification if order status is On hold

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

Is there a way to disable the "New Order" e-mail notification sent to admin when the order status is "On hold"?

Or to enable it only for "processing" status?

I also tried different things to receive the "New Order" email only when the status is "Processing", without success.

Any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

To disable "New Order" e-mail notification sent to admin when the order status is "on-hold", use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'disable_new_order_for_on_hold_order_status', 10, 2 );
function disable_new_order_for_on_hold_order_status( $recipient, $order = false ) {
    if ( ! $order || ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) 
        return $recipient;

    return $order->get_status() === 'on-hold' ? '' : $recipient;
}
```

---

To enable "New Order" e-mail notification sent to admin **only when order status is "processing"** replace in the function above:

```
return = $order->get_status() === 'on-hold' ? '' : $recipient;
```

with the following:

```
return = $order->get_status() === 'processing' ? $recipient : '';
```

---

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: The first code seems to work, but I'm not receiving a New order e-mail when the status changes to "Processing".

Is there a way to enable the New Order e-mail only at Processing Status?

Comment: When the order goes from "Pending Payment" to "Processing", I'm 
receiving the e-mail admin e-mail. 

But, when goes from "On Hold" to "Processing", I don't get the New Order e-mail.

Comment: @FelipeSooUl First, I remember that you didn't provide any code attempt in your question, which is the rule on StackOverFlow. Next time, Just add a comment without removing answer acceptance and be patient… If I don't solve the problem after some time, you can remove acceptance.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for removing the answer acceptance. I'm kinda new at stack overflow, so I'm still learning some stuff about WordPress / Woocommerce. I'll test the code tonight. Thank you so much for your support, @LoicTheAztec.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec - after using the snippet you provided and replacing  
`return = $order->get_status() === 'on-hold' ? '' : $recipient;` 

with 

`return = $order->get_status() === 'processing' ? $recipient : '';` an error was returned.

I believe what you meant to write was `return $order->get_status() === 'processing' ? $recipient : '';`